# Name of "statistical" method

Tags: terminology, multiarmed-bandit, contextual-bandit

This might be a too specific question, but I have no idea where else to turn to.

I'm creating Multi-Armed Bandits with different approaches. One approach has been to create a randomized matrix and multiply it to a user vector.

By this method I'm extending the user vector to a larger vector, hopefully containing more/better information, since the vector should in some way have found more relations between the different contexts I've used.

```
UserVector1 * BigMatrixA -> BigUserVector1
UserVector2 * BigMatrixA -> BigUserVector2
```

Now you can compare BigUserVector1 with BigUserVector2 and maybe find "new" similarities that wasn't showing when comparing UserVector1 with UserVector2.

I've implemented this in my thesis, but I haven't found any mention of it in papers. So, the question is, what's this called? I've tried searching for "Compressed Sensing" and "Random Projections", but I've found nothing that I can cite in my thesis.

Comment: @RobertStigsson: Wouldn't this be the opposite of dimensionality reduction. It seems to be the opposite of singular value decomposition.

Comment: It seems you want to go from a low-dimensional to a high-dimensional space. You also seem to work explicitly with the high dimensional vectors. With Kernel methods it is possible to operate on high-dimensional spaces without the need of obtaining the high-dimensional vectors explicitly. This is possible by applying the so called Kernel trick.

Comment: This doesn't work (the way you think it does): BigUserVector1 and BigUserVector2 will still live in a subspace of the same dimension as the dimension of UserVector1 and UserVector2. If you don't believe me, do this a bunch of times, stack the BigUserVectors in a matrix, and look at a PCA elbow plot. If you are doing this and get some kind of improved quantitative results, share them with us, and we may be able to help you understand what's actually happening.